# Testing C++ code and IsBadWritePtr

Tags: c++, windows, testing

I am currently writing some basic tests for some functions of my C++ code (it is a game engine that I am writing mostly for educational purposes). One of the features I want to test is the memory allocation code. The tests currently consist of a function that runs every startup if the code is in debug mode. This forces me to always test the code when I am debugging.

To test my memory allocation code my instinct is to do something like this:

```
int* test = MemoryManager::AllocateMemory<int>();
assert(!IsBadWritePtr(test, sizeof(int)), "Memory allocation test failed: allocate");

MemoryManager::FreeMemory(test);
assert(IsBadWritePtr(test, sizeof(int)), "Memory free test failed: free");
```

This code is working fine, but all the resources I can find say not to use the `IsBadWritePtr` function (this is a WinAPI function for those unfamiliar). Is the use of this function OK in this case? The three main warnings against using it I found were:

## This might cause issues with guard pages

This isn't an issue as the memory allocation code is right there and I know I am not allocating a guard page.

## It's better to fail earlier

This isn't a consideration as I am literally using it to fail as early as possible.

## It isn't thread safe

The test code is executed right at the beginning of execution, long before any other threads exist. It also acts on memory to which no other pointers are created, and therefore could not exist in other threads.

So basically I want to know if the use of this function is a good idea in this case, and if there is anything I am missing about the function. I am also aware that something that points to the wrong place will still pass this test, but it at least detects most memory allocation errors, right (what are the chances I get a pointer to valid memory if the allocation fails?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to write this as a comment but it's too long.

I'll bring up the elephant in the room: why don't you just test for failure in the traditional way (by returning null or throwing an exception)?

Nevermind the fact that IsBadWritePtr is so frowned upon (even its documentation says that it's obsolete and you shouldn't use it), but your use case doesn't even seem appropriate. From the MSDN documentation:

> This function is typically used when working with pointers returned from third-party libraries, where you cannot determine the memory management behavior in the third-party DLL.

But you are not using it to test anything passed/returned from a DLL, you just seem to be using it to test for allocation success, which is not only unnecessary (because you already know that from the return value of HeapAlloc, GlobalAlloc, etc.), but it's not what IsBadWritePtr is intended for.

Also, testing for allocation success is not something you should only do in debug mode, or with asserts, as it's obviously out of your control and you can't try to "fix" it by debugging.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. As to why this is only happening in debug mode, it is part of my test that the allocator is working properly at all. It allocates a little memory, tests it is allocated, frees it, then tests it is free. This is to ensure the allocator is working and fail early instead of waiting for it to be used. There are also checks in the code when I use it, but I thought it would be weird to leave something as crucial as the memory allocator out of the tests!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @user1610015's answer, there one reason why `IsBadReadPtr` should NOT work in your scenario.

Basically `IsBadReadPtr` works on *whole page* granularity. This means for the above code to be correct each and every allocation you make will consume a whole page (min 4KB).

Modern allocators use a variety of tricks to pack lots of allocations into pages (low fragmentation bucket heaps, linked lists of allocations, etc). If you don't pack small allocation like this then thinks like stl maps and other libraries which use lots of small allocations will absolutely kill your game (both in memory use and the fact that cache coherency will be killed with so much unused padding).

As a side not, your last comment about thread safety is dangerous. Lots of apps and libraries you link to can spawn threads off with global object constructors (and so run before main is called) and other tricks to insert code into your process. So I would definitely check this is the case with your code right now but more importantly later as you add 3rd party libraries to you code check it then.

Comment: Thanks, at the moment my code only depends on the Windows API, but I will keep what you said about thread safety in mind if I do add any other libraries. The memory in question is allocated via `VirtualAlloc`, so it is allocated on page boundaries: `The size of the region, in bytes. If the lpAddress parameter is NULL, this value is rounded up to the next page boundary.` I still agree with you though, this use is wrong and I was mostly just curious to the reason why.